# Displaying data with total no of data

Tags: oracle

I have a table named customer in oracle database. Now I have to select the data from customer table like this.

```
   ID    Name   Address      DOB

   1     Ram      goa      2/2/1988
   2     Rahul    ktm      3/3/1987
   3     Hari     pkr      4/4/1986

 TOTAL                       3
```

There is no problem in getting the data using select query from table. But I got problem in displaying the Total count. I have to display only using query. Please help soon.

Thanks In advance ...

Comment: check my updated answer by using `union all` or by `union`..

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `NUM_ROWS` in `oracle`

```
SELECT NUM_ROWS FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = table_name;
```

or you may try for `COUNT` as well like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTALROWS FROM tablename;
```

If you want to `select all rows` values along with `count` then try

```
SELECT ID,Name,Address,DOB,COUNT(*) as TOTALROWS
FROM tablename;
```

You can complete this task using `Union All` or `Union` like

```
select ID,Name,Address,DOB from tablename
union all
select 'Toal','','',count(*) from tablename;
```

or

```
select ID,Name,Address,DOB from tablename
union
select 'Toal','','',count(*) from tablename;
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but this solution gives total in a column. But I need exactly same as the table as shown in question

Comment: so you want to show the `total rows count` on `another row` or `next row` underneath `DOB`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display total number of rows you should use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM customers
```

If you are trying to have a single select query that will display the content and beneath it the total amount of content it is impossible IMHO / very unproper usage of SQL. your queries have different columns and that is sufficient to determine it cannot be done in a singe query.

If you want however to have the data in a separate column this can be done:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers,(SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM CUSTOMERS)
```

will add the total column to your query output.

And for or a single SELECT query:

```
SELECT id,name,address,dob,COUNT(*) as TOTAL
FROM customer
```

See fiddle for full code:
[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c49c/6)

Comment: But I have to do these things in a single select statement. Isn't there any solution to this?

Comment: I've added a solution for a single select statement

Comment: If you need the solution do display output as in your answer that is quite impossible (I try to never say never but this is very close to it)
why do you need it to be this way? perhaps you issue has other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select  ID ,Name ,Address ,DOB, count(*)
from    mytable
group by rollup((ID ,Name ,Address ,DOB))
```